# Generating Averages from my data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 4 months of data that looks like this.

I have been using it to make a scatter plot for each month. along with the scatter plot I would like to use it to make averages of mood for the 6 different intervals of time for each day.

example:

- month of may 7:30-9:30 averages 2.3,
- month of may 9:30-12:30 averages 1.2...
  (those are not the actual values)

the scale goes from 1 to 3. I feel like I don't have this data layed out correctly to do that though.

is there a way I can do this without having to spend a lengthy amount of time rearranging the way I have my data layed out?

this may have to be done for many more months, so if I have to spend a lot of time on this I will, just my time is limited so I need to do this as efficiently as I can.

a better question would be, what is the most efficient way to use my data to generate monthly averages for each time interval?

```
may 3  7:30 AM - 9:30 AM    2
May 3  9:30 AM - 12:30 PM   2
May 3  12:30 PM -3:00 PM    2
May 3  3:00 PM - 5:30 PM    2
May 3  5:30PM - 7:00 PM     2
May 3  7:00 PM - 11:00 PM   2
May 4  7:30 AM - 9:30 AM    3
May 4  9:30 AM - 12:30 PM   3
May 4  12:30 PM -3:00 PM    3
May 4  3:00 PM - 5:30 PM    2
May 4  5:30PM - 7:00 PM     2
May 4  7:00 PM - 11:00 PM   2
```

Comment: Is your data all in a single cell or are they separated, for example do you have A1 with "May 3" then B1 with "7:30 - 9:30" then C1 with "2" or is everything in A1? If you have then separated then this is relatively simple, if not then I still think it would be possible with a text search.

Comment: Almost seperated like you said. A1 is date and time. A2  is mood. Formating it like you said would be a breeze. What would i do from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical job for a pivot table:

- split your day and month in different columns
- insert a pivot table based on your data
- move month and time columns to "rows"

  - time will be ordered alphabetically, you can set your preferred order by drag and drop values
- move your value column to "values" and set it to be aggregated as "average"
- you can find more fine tuning options in pivotTable tools groups in the ribbon

[image]